# How to checkout only working tree

Tags: git

I'd like to get only a working tree from specified commit. No history, no branch switching, no merging. Just as I wrote all files manually.

What command or chain of commands can do that?

I could just clone repository to another directory and copy all files. I would resort to such way only if no built-in git commands could be of help.

Comment: Do you want to checkout few files alone?

Comment: I want to checkout all files. Get files as they were in the commit state. Add added files, remove removed files

Comment: So you want to move to a previous commit right..

Comment: Not, I want to move to another commit. Not preceding, not succeeding.

Comment: I'm not getting what result you want to achieve, if you could just give a small eg or explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) for that, for example:

```
git archive --format zip --output /path/to/output.zip <commit number>
```

Also, another option is to checkout a specific commit and delete the `.git` directory at the project root, as all of the repository information is stored there.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is `get checkout --patch` and then press *a* key to apply all changes.